# Streaming audio file from Shotcast and Icecast server

Tags: c++, audio, stream, audio-streaming

I am trying build an C++ application, which will try to connect Shoutcast/Icecast server, get an audio file, then stream the audio file into audio device. There is winamp application in windows, which already does the same. But I would like the same kind of application in C++. I have read the http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html link. But not sure how I should start. I would need specific help on this: a) How do I connect to shotcast server? b) get the audio file url? c) How should I start streaming? I have built one socket program which can connect  to server, can send/recv binary data. Hope this can help here. But I am unable to start on above three points? I have read stackoverflow urls on this:

[Stream getUserMedia to an Icecast server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973597/stream-getusermedia-to-an-icecast-server)
[Audio streaming using C++ tutorial and sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579217/audio-streaming-using-c-tutorial-and-sample-code)
http://forums.radiotoolbox.com/viewtopic.php?t=74

But could not help much. 
Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

SHOUTcast/Icecast are essentially HTTP.  You should be searching on how to make an HTTP request.

There is a small difference for SHOUTcast servers though... the status line they return is non-standard:

```
ICY 200 OK
```

A normal status line would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Once you learn how to make an HTTP request, you will be streaming.  Later on if you want to get the metadata, you can follow the SmackFu link you posted.